# 6x &nbsp; convert to css?

Tags: html, css

How can I convert my 6x `&nbsp;` to CSS

I have the

```html
 <ul data-role="listview"
        data-inset="true"
        data-theme="d"
        data-divider-theme="e"
        data-count-theme="a"
    >
        <li>
            <img    src="https://www.lifewire.com/thmb/SY5rof4hEZ4WkWqolEFWwZEIqAI=/774x0/filters:no_upscale():max_bytes(150000):strip_icc():format(webp)/yahoo-logo-2019-879b7bed612d4bbc97065dce2a0f2d73.png"
                alt="yahoo-mail"
                class="ui-li-icon"/>
            <a href="./about">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Yahoo!</a>
            <span class="ui-li-count">3</span>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

following code:

Comment: Why don't you use padding instead  <style> #mydiv { padding-left:20px; } </style>

Comment: A non-breaking space is going to be a different size depending on your font.   Use margins or padding instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove all the `&nbsp;` and use padding:

```
a{padding-left:20px}
```

Comment: yep but you need to be careful when you give a padding it will appear on all of you link.

Comment: of course, this is just an example of how to apply css to an a tag as op requested

Comment: why exectly 20px??

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="d" data-divider-theme="e" data-count-theme="a">
        <li>
            <img src="/css/images/yahoo-mail.png" alt="yahoo-mail" class="ui-li-icon"/>
            <a href="./about"><span class="link-text">Yahoo!</span></a><span class="ui-li-count">3</span>
        </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.link-text:before {
    content: '      '; /* 6 spaces */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give span tag in a tag.

```
<a href="./about"><span></span>Yahoo!</a>
```

then give padding to span.

Answer (score 0):

There's many ways to do this. I'd probably add a margin to the icon image:

```
.ul-li-icon {
  margin-right: 20px
}
```